# How do you assign "null" to a Delphi.net Nullable

Tags: nullable, delphi.net

How do you assign null to a Delphi.net Nullable? I have a field which previously contained a value , I need to clear its value back to null.

```
depth : Nullable<Double>;

Procedure ClearDepth;
begin 
    depth := Nil;
end;
```

The above creates the error `Error: E2010 Incompatible types : 'Nullable<System.Double>' and 'Pointer'`. using `Null` in place of `Nil` gives the same error with `Variant` in place of `Pointer`. I wondered if I should be using a special constructor to generate a null nullable but I couldn't see one in the documentation?

The following works but doesn't seem like a great solution, can anyone suggest a better way?

```
Procedure ClearDepth;
var
    uninitialisedValue : Nullable<Double>;
begin 
    depth := uninitialisedValue;
end;
```

Comment: Which Delphi.net? Delphi Prism?

Comment: @springy76 This looks like Delphi.net rather than Prism because Prism has nullable baked into the language.

Answer (score 3):

You need this syntax:

```
depth := Default(Nullable<Double>);
```

Comment: perfect, thanks. Should've just tried it to see what happened!

Comment: @Thom Out of interest, do both of these versions work? I have to confess to never having used delphi.net!

Comment: The first works but not the second (`DEFAULT standard function expects a type identifier`)

Comment: @Thom Thanks. Answer updated. Looks pretty verbose when compared to Prism or C#.

Comment: Ugh I spoke too soon. That line compiles, but is apparently ignored at runtime. When will I learn, compiling != correct...

Answer (score 1):

The type `Nullable<T>` is a `struct`. That means it has a public parameterless constructor. In the case of this type, that's the value that represents `null`. In C#, you would use:

```
new Nullable<Double>()
```

Another way to get the same value in C# would be

```
default(Nullable<Double>)
```

In both cases, I don't know the syntax for Delphi. In the second case, I don't know whether something like this can be even represented there.

**EDIT:** Apparently, you can use the second version in Delphi, but not the equivalent of the first one. That's quite surprising to me.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see how to do either in Delphi. `Nullable<Double>.Create(1.0)` (Delphi constructor syntax) works fine, but `Nullable<Double>.Create()` gives an error about no overload with that number of parameters, suggesting the default constructor isn't exposed :(

Comment: update - sorry I was wrong, even Default(T) doesn't work in Delphi (it compiles, but is completely ignored at runtime, leaving depth with its previous value).